# How can I allow user to run Docker application with different arguments

Tags: java, docker

I have built a [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) image for my Java application - https://bitbucket.org/ijabz/songkongdocker/src/master/Dockerfile

The last line is

```
CMD /opt/songkong/songkongremote.sh
```

the (simplified) contents of songremote.sh are

```
#!/bin/sh
umask 000
./jre/bin/java-jar lib/songkong-6.9.jar -r
```

and it works fine.

However I have a customer who wants to run songkong with the -m option and a path

e.g

```
#!/bin/sh
umask 000
./jre/bin/java-jar lib/songkong-6.9.jar -m /users/music
```

1. So is there a way a single docker can allow for two different command to be run, or do I have to build another docker.
2. Either way how do I allow /users/music to be provided by user

The full contents of songkongremote are a bit more complicated, since more options have to be passed to Java

*#!/bin/sh
umask 000
./jre/bin/java -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=60 -XX:MetaspaceSize=45 -Dcom.mchange.v2.log.MLog=com.mchange.v2.log.jdk14logging.Jdk14MLog -Dorg.jboss.logging.provider=jdk -Djava.util.logging.config.class=com.jthink.songkong.logging.StandardLogging -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2 --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED -jar lib/songkong-6.9.jar -r*

**Update**
I follows Cascaders answer and it has done something (look at Execution Command)

[image]

but *songkong.sh* is acting as if no parameters have been passed at all (rather than -r option passed).

songkong.sh (renamed from songkongremote.sh) now contains

```
#!/bin/sh
umask 000
./jre/bin/java  -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=60 -XX:MetaspaceSize=45 -Dcom.mchange.v2.log.MLog=com.mchange.v2.log.jdk14logging.Jdk14MLog -Dorg.jboss.logging.provider=jdk -Djava.util.logging.config.class=com.jthink.songkong.logging.StandardLogging -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2 --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED -jar lib/songkong-6.10.jar "$@"
```

and the end of Dockerfile is now

```
EXPOSE 4567

ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/tini"]

# Config, License, Logs, Reports and Internal Database
VOLUME /songkong

# Music folder should be mounted here
VOLUME /music

WORKDIR /opt/songkong

ENTRYPOINT /opt/songkong/songkong.sh
CMD ["-r"]
```

I don't understand if okay that there are two entrypoints or the signifcance of the sbin/tini one

Comment: the first entrypoint will be ignore, you can not define two in Dockerfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So is there a way a single docker can allow for two different command
> to be run, or do I have to build another docker.

Yes, you can handle this using single Dockerfile base on command with help of entrypoint.

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
umask 000
if [ "$1" == "-m" ];then
    echo "starting container with -m option"
    ./jre/bin/java-jar lib/songkong-6.9.jar "$@"
else
    ./jre/bin/java-jar lib/songkong-6.9.jar -r
fi
```

so if the docker run command look like this

```
docker run -it --rm myimage -m /users/music
```

it will execute first condition

But `if [ "$1" == "-m" ]` this will break if user pass like `"-m /users/music"` in double-quotes, as the condition only checking for first argument. you can adjust this accordingly.

So the Dockerfile will only contain entrypoint

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/songkong/songkongremote.sh"]
```

Or you can `CMD` specify in Dockerfile

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/songkong/songkongremote.sh"]
CMD ["-m", "/song/myfile]"
```

**update:**

You can not define two entrypoint per docker image, the first will be ignore.

Now to process to argument from `CMD` you should use array type syntax otherwise it will seems empty

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/songkong/songkong.sh"]
CMD ["-r"]
```

Comment: thx looks good, but would should end of docker file itself now look like ?

Comment: updated answer. `ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/songkong/songkongremote.sh"]`

Comment: any luck or attemp?

Comment: Hi, I have tried the very simailr answer from Cascader and it doesnt seem to be quite working (updated question with results)

Comment: updated. coincidence is I also looking in to your new question :D

Comment: Thankyou did not understand the significance of the brackets. Okay now works (sort of), if I specify -h it shows the command help and then stops as expected. But if I  pass-m /users/music to Execution Command/Command it runs but Synology will not let me access logs or terminal I guess because long running process, but if instead I pass -m /users/music & to run in background then it fails to launch with 'run command format' error ?

Comment: Sorry, actually seems to be workmng now okay, i can acces logs and terminal and I can stop it by pressing Cntl-C in the terminal. Okay thankyoufoir your help and accepting your answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use `ENTRY` point for the command, and `CMD` only for arguments

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/tini", "/opt/songkong/songkongremote.sh" ]

CMD [] # Arguments are passed here
```

You also need to handle arguments in your .sh file:

```
#!/bin/sh
umask 000
./jre/bin/java-jar lib/songkong-6.9.jar "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to `ENTRYPOINT` instead of `CMD`. Your docker file will look like:

```
...
ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/songkong/songkongremote.sh" ]
...
```

Your customers would then run your image as:

`docker run img -r`

or

`docker run img -m /users/music`

You can even alter your bash script to accept arguments and pass those arguments using the same method.

If you need to provide *default arguments* and the ability to override them on demand, the following approach will work:

Dockerfile:

```
...
ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/songkong/songkongremote.sh" ]
CMD ["-r"]
...
```

Your modified script:

```
#!/bin/sh 
umask 000 
./jre/bin/java \
-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=60 \
-XX:MetaspaceSize=45 \
-Dcom.mchange.v2.log.MLog=com.mchange.v2.log.jdk14logging.Jdk14MLog \
-Dorg.jboss.logging.provider=jdk \
-Djava.util.logging.config.class=com.jthink.songkong.logging.StandardLogging \
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2 \
--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED \
-jar lib/songkong-6.9.jar "$@"
```

Then, when customers run `docker run img` the CMD parameter will kick-in, but when they run `docker run img -m /users/music` the entrypoint command will be executed with the provided arguments.

Comment: okay, thanks. But can I have a default because majority of customers run on Synology or Qnap nas so they dont invoke docker itself with commands, so I want the usual case to continue working without them having to actively chnage anything

Comment: I have updated my answer @PaulTaylor. Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21564990/1505146) which explains the mechanism.

Comment: ok, thx. sorry I simplified the original .sh script but its actually a bit more complex than that, Ive updated question, also note the umask cmd is required as well

Comment: That's ok, I can update my answer to use your script. andreoss's answer already covered that

Comment: Hi, I have tried it and it doesnt seem to be quite working (updated question with results)

Comment: Please correct your syntax: it should be `ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/songkong/songkong.sh"]`, not `ENTRYPOINT /opt/songkong/songkong.sh`

Comment: You can use [this](https://gist.github.com/tpapad28/ed3b4a383b5fe768e5bf98290e4e18d5) for reference